# Html table export to excel javascript.But I have interesting problem

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <title>Rapor Al</title>
    <script>
        
    function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\uFEFF', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
       
}
         
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I try html table export to excel with using javascript. All is well but. I have a problem.Please compare the two pictures. Where is from coming first and second row at excel file? I can't find :( Please help me friends...

[Html table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHuzt.png)

[Excel file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnkem.png)

Comment: var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');, it has some linefeeds ate the beginning, try innerHTML, or check the table.